# Flash loader demands library files in folder other than folder where main project file is?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

i have situation in which i have some library projects, say

> "DataProcessors","Lib2"

, included in my lets say "MainProject" (a web project) placed on directory

> "E:\bin-debug\MainProject.swf"

, when i build the project it automatically place all the libs .swf in its "E:\bin-debug" folder, but when i debug or run the project it it gives loading error that

> "E:\DataProcessors.swf"

**not found** but i have those lib files on

> "E:\bin-debug\DataProcessors.swf"..

what could be the possible errors.. i have included the lib files like this

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9bfa02879c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9bfa02879c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your references in the project properties and make sure they are pointed to the correct place. I can't remember te exact tab of the top of my head, but external references are in there somewhere (build paths maybe?)